# TensorFlow Profiler not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I installed TensorFlow 1.4 using pip.

Now, I want to use the native [TensorFlow Profiler (tfprof)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md). 
In the readme it is shown that there should be a comand-line tool `tfprof`. I can't find the tool `tfprof`, nor how to access the webUI also shown in this readme.

When I try the solution shown in the code box *"When using lower-level APIs with a Session object. User can have"*, it prints continuously the information which should be shown by the cli tool, and creates profiling files in `/tmp/train_dir`, which I don't know how to read.

So, where can I find the cli tool and the webui, or how can I build them?

Moreover, is `tfprof` using *`tensorflow.python.client timeline`* for tracing, or are there any benefits in using this for tracing?

Answer (score 0):

To access the tfprof CLI tool you can build the profiler module. Assuming that you have setup the build environment ([follow this link for help](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)), you can build the profiler module by issuing the command:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/core/profiler:profiler
```

from inside of the cloned tensorflow's directory. Once built, you can use as specified in this [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler). More info on this is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/g3doc/command_line.md). As far as UI is concerned you should follow the instructions given in the [official repo for UI](https://github.com/tensorflow/profiler-ui.git).